# Adding/deleting data into local browser storage using a button, and displaying it in a UI table (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browser, local-storage

I would like to have a react app that uses local storage to store data, and display that data in a table in the user interface (UI).

I want to be able to submit an entry into local storage by clicking a button (SUBMIT), and then be able to delete an entry in local storage by clicking another button (DELETE).

And whatever data is in local storage I would like it to be displayed in a small table in the UI even after the browser is refreshed.

I have used this tutorial (https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react#local-storage-in-react) as a basis for the local storage and provided the code I am using from that tutorial below. But in the tutorial, the data is submitted by typing into a box and having it displayed in a paragraph. And from the developer tools I can see this is only for one key value pair.

**CODE:**

```
import React from 'react';

const useStateWithLocalStorage = localStorageKey => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) || ''
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, value);
  }, [value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useStateWithLocalStorage(
    'myValueInLocalStorage'
  );

  const onChange = event => setValue(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React with Local Storage!</h1>

      <input value={value} type="text" onChange={onChange} />

      <p>{value}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

From the tutorial, I believe data will be:

**Submitted** into local storage using `localStorage.setItem('myData', data)`

**Displayed** in the table using `localStorage.getItem('myData')`

**Deleted** from local storage/table using `localStorage.removeItem('myData')`or, `localStorage.clear()`

My guess is each one of the previous pieces of code will be in a a separate function that gets called in `return()`.

I have attached below, what I am trying to create, specifically, what the UI will look like:

[image]

Submitting data to local storage is done with the SUBMIT button, while data is deleted from local storage using the DELETE button in the table, while everything that is displayed in the table is from local storage.

Let me know if more information is needed. There are so many ways to do this, and I honestly do not know what to do. For example, if I need to create a class with multiple functions in the class that do what I described above (e.g a function for submitting, another for deleting, and one for retrieving data from the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store arrays in localstorage use JSON.stringify otherwise you will end up storing a comma separated string

So the code for the custom hook will need to be changed to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

```
const useStateWithLocalStorageArray = localStorageKey => {  
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) || '[]' ) 
  );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(value))    
  }, [value]);
  return [value, setValue];
};
```

Here is the full source in Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/NuSBnLpPpoOmmEE6

Comment: Is there a way to take it a step further and add multiple values at once that are grouped together? So every submission would have 3 entries? For example, Name, Job and Age. Not sure if this is possible, but in local storage I think it would look something like this for 2 entries under Value, [[Name, Job, Age], [Name2, Job2, Age2]].

Comment: Sure you can , please check the updated code https://plnkr.co/edit/NuSBnLpPpoOmmEE6